# Is there a need to prune devices in FCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm considering to move from GCM to FCM

GCM has notion of pruning devices (stop sending pushes to devices that doesn't receive pushes)

Should I do to eliminate such devices when using FCM ?
Or is it handled automatically by FCM? (I only send messages to a `topic` and fcm server will know which devices it needs to send the messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending to individual tokens then FCM has the same requirement. However if you are using topics then FCM will automatically stop sending to invalid tokens.